# How to get the date from default date format in php

Tags: php, date

I have the date in the form `Sat Aug 08 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530` (India Standard Time). How can I get the date of the format "**yyyy/mm/dd**".

Comment: use date function of php

Comment: try this : - SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo date('Y/m/d', strtotime('Sat Aug 08 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530') );
```

Comment: its everytime giving 1970-01-01. I am not able to get a correct date. My date is in a variable $var.
$var="Sat Aug 08 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530"
so i fetch it as $date=date('y-m-d',strtotime($var)); //1970-01-01